# How to cast TextView with my custom TextView?

Tags: java, android

I take text view instance from here:

```
    TextView date = null;

        try {
            date = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.some_textview, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

I created my custom textview:

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView{

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }


}
```

Now i want to cast those:

```
MyTextView my = (MyTextView)date;
```

I get exeption for this one:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to com.myapp.name.MyTextView
```

So how it should be done ?

Thanks.

***Edit:***

If i declare `date` as `MyTextView`, still get same exception, ther is my xml of some_textview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a template for date text view"  
        />
```

Comment: do this `MyTextView date = (MyTextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.some_textview, null);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your XML-layout  `R.layout.some_textview` resource correct?

Don't use

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    />
```

You have to use your custom class in your XML:

```
<com.your.package.MyTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    />
```

It's very important the class-path is correct!

Answer (score 2):

You could directly use your MyTextView in the XML, instead of `<TextView />` use `<com.myapp.name.MyTextView />`

Then in your code use com.myapp.name.MyTextView instead of TextView.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `date` as `MyTextView`. You tried to cast a TextView object to subclass of TextView, but the object is not an instance of the subclass type ([see example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like here:

```
    MyTextView date = null;

    try {
        date = (MyTextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.some_textview, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```